# Where condition in Razor DropdownList MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor, lambda

I am generating a dropdownlist in MVC. I have a model in view which have two list values. My code looks like

```
@Html.DropDownList("Test", new SelectList(
                            Model.Test.Where(i=>i.Id = *from other list*), "Id", "Name"))
```

In my Model I have two Lists :
`List<Test>` and `List<Test2>`. What I am trying is generate dropdown where Test1.Id is equal to Test2.Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Test", new SelectList(
     Model.Test.Where(i=>Model.Test2.Any(ii=> i.Id == ii.Id)), "Id", "Name"))
```

Example with `Any` statement:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
        List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "D", "F", "A", "B", "E" };

        var result = listB.Where(lb => listA.Any(la => la == lb));
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
    }
```

**Result**: 2